# Pyramid Thread Locals - why is get_current_request a bad idea?

Tags: python, pyramid

[The Pyramid documentation of thread locals](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/threadlocals.html) states that

> `get_current_request` should never be called in resource code. If a resource needs access to the request, it should be passed the request by a view callable.

I was searching for a way to modify my resource code. I always pass the request directly from view callable to the resource so that I can:-

1. Check for permissions (request.has_permission())
2. Update the session flash with user feedback (session.flash())

The latter can be done without passing the request in (using inspect to get the current session) but the equivalent to that for the request itself is to use get_current_request, which is stated to be a bad idea.

1. Why is it a bad idea?
2. Is the actual bad idea the whole 'accessing a pseudo-global value' thing (which inspect also does)?
3. How can I check permissions for the concept of the 'current user' without having to pass the request around (or passing request.user etc.)
4. Is the fact that I'm considering this evidence of a bad design? Do ACLs somehow do all this already without requiring the passing around of request objects?

Comment: I don't want to talk for others, but I personally pass things that are needed in function calls. If a function needs the current user, I pass it in the function call, etc. I never had to rely on thread locals. Personally, I prefer to have code that is self contained (no surprising side effects) and tend toward a more "functional" design (receive args, return something using those args). Also, I try to isolate the HTTP layer of the app from the business logic code (e.g. calling a function from the command line, `request` does not make sense).

Comment: Thanks @Antoine, does that mean permission handling is not done in your business logic code?

Comment: Exact. I use the ACL from Pyramid. It also has the advantage of giving context to the view function (no data fetching from the view function). Also, I normally add form validation outside the view `@view_config(decorator=some_validation)`. That way, when the view function receives the request, it can call the business logic function almost always on the first line and return on the second line (you already know the object, the user & permission ok). E.g. `edit_document(dbsession=request.dbsession, document=request.context.document, content=request.validated['content'], by_user=request.user)`.

Comment: Thanks, will check that out and possibly write up an answer